# Why \mathbf cannot be redefined?

Tags: math-mode, macros

I have a tex file as following:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\let\mathbf\symbfup
\let\emph\symbfup
\let\textbf\symbfup

% same result with other ways:
%\LetLtxMacro{\mathbf}{\symbfup}
%\renewcommand{\mathbf}[1]{\symbfup{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\mathbf}{\symbfup}

\begin{document}

\[
1.\mathbf\Omega 2.\emph\Omega 3.\textbf\Omega 
\]


\end{document}
```

And the output is:

[image]

From the log file it says `Missing character: There is no  in font [lmroman10-bold]:mapping=tex-text;`, which is the behavior of the native `\mathbf` (thus I am trying to use `\symbfup` instead of `\mathbf`).

Comment: unicode-math makes almost all its definitions in AtBeginDocument so making redefinitions in the preamble is tricky

Comment: I don’t think the problem is with Unicode-math, as I could redefine those commands to any other except for \mathbf. And I wasn’t able to redefine any other command (\textit for example) to \mathbf either.

Comment: See Davislor's answer, the issues are all directly related to unicode-math, you are redefining core latex commands and unicode-math does all its definitions at begin document so after your redefinitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is `\usepackage[mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}`.  See section 4.4.2 of [the manual.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf)

You do not want to redefine `\textbf`, as this is a LaTeX command that already does something else in both text and math mode, and redefining it this way will cause bold text to break.  You similarly do not want to redefine `\emph`.  A standard way to get what you want is `\textnormal{\bfseries v}`.

If you want to select both bold text and bold math, use `\bfseries\boldmath`.  Then load an OpenType math font that comes with a bold version, such as XITS Math, or declare one with `\setmathfont[version=bold]{Some Font Math Bold}`.

To answer the literal question you asked, `unicode-math` does most of its definitions at the end of the preamble (which makes it more compatible with other packages), so you would need to redefine most of its commands inside `\AtBeginDocument`.